# Настройка ODBC для PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, odbc

Пытаюсь настроить удаленное подключение к PostgreSQL 9.2 под виндой. На сервере в `pg_hba.conf` дописал

```
host all postgres 192.168.0.101 trust
```

а в postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Есть приложение, использующее ADO.NET. Для подключение к БД использую OdbcConnection. Вылетает с ошибкой:

> [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC]
>   Источник данных не найден и не указан
>   драйвер, используемый по умолчанию

ODBC коннектор установлен, но при попытке тестового подключения сообщение, что сервер не отвечает. Понимаю, что вопрос не совсем сюда... но все-таки: что с этим зверем (PostgreSQL) делать в данном вопросе?

P.S. использую его первый раз, нужен замер времени выполнения запроса из моего клиента к разным типам СУБД, поэтому и юзаю Postgre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну мне кажется проще всего начать с того, что:

- Создайте файл anyname.udl на рабочем столе или где душе угодно.
- Откройте его сопоставленной программой.
- При помощи этого диспетчера настройте подключение, через выбор соответствующего провайдера и его необходимых настроек.
- Сохраните изменения.
- Откройте измененный файл блокнотом, в виде текста вы увидите строку подключения.

Далее эту строку можете использовать на свой вкус присыпая ее паролями и логинами по необходимости.

PS: Есть подозрения, что вы либо действительно не установили провайдер, либо установили провайдер не соответствующий разрядности приложения, который его использует... нечто подобное у меня было как-то давно и не правда.